# Add Custon Class as List in Dictionary And Conversion

Tags: c#, json, dictionary

hi every one i want some thing that i have my own custom class menuestructure and i want to first make and list of this type and will create multiple object then want to pass and add in dictionary and then also convert to Json must be appreciated if someone can help me thanx.
here is my code with comments that actually what i want please it will better if little bit add lines in code to how can i achieve it .

Code:-

```
public string GetMenue()
{
    List<MenueStructure> chlidObj1 = new List<MenueStructure>();
    chlidObj1.Add(new MenueStructure { ID = "1", ParentID = "", ChildID = "1", MenuName = "Registration", MenuLink = "Registration.aspx"});
    chlidObj1.Add(new MenueStructure { ID = "2", ParentID = "1", ChildID = "2", MenuName = "Assign Subject", MenuLink = "AssignSubject.aspx"});

    List<MenueStructure> chlidObj2 = new List<MenueStructure>();
    chlidObj2.Add(new MenueStructure { ID = "1", ParentID = "", ChildID = "1", MenuName = "Registration", MenuLink = "Registration.aspx"});
    chlidObj2.Add(new MenueStructure { ID = "2", ParentID = "1", ChildID = "2", MenuName = "Assign Subject", MenuLink = "AssignSubject.aspx"});

    Dictionary<string, List<MenueStructure>> childs = new Dictionary<string, MenueStructure[]>()
             {
                 // here error no overload method to take one argument
                 childs.Add("TEACHERS", chlidObj1);
                 childs.Add("TEACHERS", chlidObj1);
             };
```

And then i want to create Json from this dictionary how can it possible .
and return as a string . help me around this how will do 
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

convert from `Dictionary` to `Json` and vice-versa is very easy given that you have to install and use [Json.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/json) library in your project.

### Serializing the Dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, List<MenueStructure>> childs = new Dictionary<string, List<MenueStructure>>
                                                              {
                                                                  {"TEACHERS", chlidObj1},
                                                                  {"STUDENTS", chlidObj2}
                                                              };

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(childs, Formatting.Indented);
```

### Deserializing the Dictionary:

```
var deserializeObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<MenueStructure>>>(json);
```

So your `GetMenue()` looks like below:

```
public string GetMenue()
{
    List<MenueStructure> chlidObj1 = new List<MenueStructure>();
    chlidObj1.Add(new MenueStructure
                          {
                              ID = "1",
                              ParentID = "",
                              ChildID = "1",
                              MenuName = "Registration",
                              MenuLink = "Registration.aspx"
                          });

    chlidObj1.Add(new MenueStructure
                          {
                              ID = "2",
                              ParentID = "1",
                              ChildID = "2",
                              MenuName = "Assign Subject",
                              MenuLink = "AssignSubject.aspx"
                          });

    List<MenueStructure> chlidObj2 = new List<MenueStructure>();
    chlidObj2.Add(new MenueStructure
                          {
                              ID = "1",
                              ParentID = "",
                              ChildID = "1",
                              MenuName = "Registration",
                              MenuLink = "Registration.aspx"
                          });
    chlidObj2.Add(new MenueStructure
                          {
                              ID = "2",
                              ParentID = "1",
                              ChildID = "2",
                              MenuName = "Assign Subject",
                              MenuLink = "AssignSubject.aspx"
                          });

    Dictionary<string, List<MenueStructure>> childs = new Dictionary<string, List<MenueStructure>>
                                                              {
                                                                  {"TEACHERS", chlidObj1},
                                                                  {"STUDENTS", chlidObj2}
                                                              };

    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(childs, Formatting.Indented);
    var deserializeObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<MenueStructure>>>(json);
    return json;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing your Dictionary in the wrong way. Either you can first initialize and empty dictionary and add the items after.

```
Dictionary<string, List<MenueStructure>> childs = new Dictionary<string, MenueStructure[]>();

childs.Add("TEACHERS", chlidObj1);
childs.Add("TEACHERS", chlidObj1);
```

**OR**

You can add the items when you are initializing the Dictionary

```
Dictionary<string, List<MenueStructure>> childs = new Dictionary<string, MenueStructure[]>()
{
    { "TEACHERS", chlidObj1},
    { "TEACHERS", chlidObj1}
};
```

Comment: thnx alot oh No thnx alot but what about to this dictionary convert into json and then want derialze for these two steps what will be the @ohlmar will be very grateful.